# Leaflet map установка и подключение через NPM

Tags: webpack, leafletjs

Добавляю пакет согласно [гайду](https://leafletjs.com/download.html)
В файле js
~

```
import L from 'leaflet'
import $ from "jquery"
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

let map;
let mLayer;

$(document).ready(function () {

    map = L.map('mapid').setView([45.071089, 38.997525], 18);
    let mLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=Mytoken', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    });

    mLayer.addTo(map);


});
```

Запускаю страничку и карта отображается блоками и без загрузки стилей.
При сборке вылетают ошибки:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers.png 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)
>    @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css) 4:41-71
>    @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
>    @ ./src/main/resources/static/map/map.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8001 ./src/main/resources/static/map/map.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers-2x.png 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)
>    @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css) 5:41-74
>    @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
>    @ ./src/main/resources/static/map/map.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8001 ./src/main/resources/static/map/map.js
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png 1:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)
>    @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css) 6:41-76
>    @ ./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
>    @ ./src/main/resources/static/map/map.js
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8001 ./src/main/resources/static/map/map.js
>   ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Настройки webpackConfig:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        globalManager:
            path.join(__dirname, 'src','main', 'resources', 'static', 'adminTools','globalManager.js'),
        map:
            path.join(__dirname, 'src','main', 'resources', 'static', 'map','map.js')
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase:path.join(__dirname, 'src','main', 'resources', 'static','production'),
        compress: true,
        port: 8001,
        allowedHosts: [
            'localhost:9000'
        ],
        stats: 'errors-only', //только ошибки в лог
        clientLogLevel: 'error',

    },
    performance: { hints: false },
    output: {
        path:path.join(__dirname, 'src','main', 'resources', 'static','production'),
        filename: '[name]-min.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname,'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'adminTools'),
            path.join(__dirname,'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'map'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
        extensions: ['.html', '.js', '.json', '.scss', '.css']
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для загрузки файлов нужен `file-loader` https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader

Comment: Nikita Umnov, правильно  написал. Спасибо!